# D3 - Stacked chart display total value on top of bar

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to display the total value on top of the stacked chart, I am using D3 Stacked bar chart with Angular 7

I have tried implementing but getting an error saying **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'domain' of undefined**

Let me know whats wrong with the current implementing or appreciate you all to provide some refrences

```
// Get Stacked chart data
      let stackedJsonData = this.getStackChartData.data;
      var data = Array();

      // Loop to iterate the JSON to fetch stacked chart data
      for (let k = 0; k < stackedJsonData.length; k++) {
        var objItem = {};
        var key_name = Object.keys(stackedJsonData[k])[0];
        objItem["State"] = key_name;

        var objArray = stackedJsonData[k][key_name];

        for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
          var keyNm = "id" + (i + 1);
          objItem[keyNm.toString()] = objArray[i];
        }
        data.push(objItem);
      }

      let keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data[0]).slice(1);

      data = data.map(v => {
        v.total = keys.map(key => v[key]).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        return v;
      });

      data.sort((a: any, b: any) => b.total - a.total);

      this.x.domain(data.map((d: any) => d.State));
      this.y.domain([0, d3Array.max(data, (d: any) => d.total)]).nice();
      this.z.domain(keys);

      this.g
        .append("g")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(d3Shape.stack().keys(keys)(data))
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("fill", d => this.z(d.key))
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(d => d)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", d => this.x(d.data.State))
        .attr("y", d => this.y(d[1]))
        .attr("height", d => this.y(d[0]) - this.y(d[1]))
        .attr("width", this.x.bandwidth());


      // Draw stacked chart x-axis
      this.g
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(18," + this.height + ")")
        .attr("color", "#ebecf5")
        .call(d3Axis.axisBottom(this.x));

      //Draw stacked chart y-axis
      this.g
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("color", "#ebecf5")
        .call(d3Axis.axisLeft(this.y).ticks(null, "s"))
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", 2)
        .attr("y", this.y(this.y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5);

      // Display total value on top of stacked bar
      this.g
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(d3Shape.stack().keys(keys)(data))
        .enter()
        .attr("fill", d => this.z(d.key))
        .append("text")
        .data(d => d)
        .attr("class", "yAxis-label")
        .attr("fill", "#70747a")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", d => this.x(d.data.State))
        .attr("y", d => this.y(d[1]) - 5)
        .text(d => d.data.State);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, either `this.x`, `this.y`, or `this.z` is undefined. Do you instantiate them somewhere, like in a constructor?

Comment: No they are global variables defined as private x: any;
  private y: any;
  private z: any;

Comment: Yes, but that's not the same as instantiating them. You need to assign them to a variable like so: `this.x = d3.scaleLinear(); this.y = d3.scaleLinear();`. You may need to have different scales for different axes, like `scaleOrdinal` for colors. Have a look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/d3js/d3js_scales_api.htm for more information